# How to prevent Back date selection in Date picker dialog in android

Tags: android, datepicker

Currently I am working over my application where I have to prevent user to not to choose back date.
please suggest how to achieve this functionality. 
sorry for english, I am newbee in android

Answer (score 0):

To prevent older dates you should do this:

```
DatePicker dp = new DatePicker(this);
dp.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```